# Read Rules from a file and apply those rules to pyspark dataframe rows

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, pyspark

I have a rule book csv, data looks like this:

```
operator|lastname|operator|firstname|val

equals    | ABC    |contains| XYZ     | 2

equals  | QWE    |contains| rty     | 3
```

so if `lastname` equals ABC and `firstname` like XYZ then `val` will be 2 ,like that. this file can be changed or modified so conditions will be dynamic. Even rows can be added in future.

Now, my pyspark dataframe is:

```
lastname| firstname| service

ABC     | XYZNMO   | something

QUE     | rtysdf   | something
```

I need to apply rule from that csv file to this dataframe and add the val column. So my desired output dataframe will be like:

```
lastname| firstname| service  | val

ABC     | XYZNMO   | something| 2

QUE     | rtysdf   | something| 3
```

Remember the rule book is dynamic, rules can be added or deleted or modified anytime. Even operators in rule book can be modified.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi there is there any reason for keeping the rules into a df? For instance is there any dynamic mechanism that is generating those rules? Or you could also store them into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

Use csv parser to parse csv files and get rules data. Then programmatically, create SQL statement using rule data - something similar to:

```
query = "SELECT
        CASE WHEN lastname = 'ABC' and firstname LIKE 'XYZ%' THEN 2
             ELSE
                 CASE WHEN lastname = 'QUE' and firstname LIKE 'rty% THEN 3
             END
        END AS val
    FROM table"
```

then run:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
result_df = spark.sql(query) # above dynamic query
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can achieve it by using the below process i believe

1. Create temporary tables on top of your dataframes
2. write an SQL using Spark SQL api and keep that in text file as a single record
3. read the sql statement using
   sqlStatement=spark.sparkContext.textFile("sqllocation").first().toString()
   you prepared in step#2 and run it using spark.sql(sqlStatement)

this way you update the sql statement which is in the text file as when required